# Wordpress Docker Container Cannot Upload Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, docker

Using the `wordpress:latest` to start a docker container, after uploading a 25MB `.zip` theme file, Wordpress shows the error

```
Are you sure you want to do this?

Please try again.
```

The docker container was started using

```
docker run -d \
--link mysql:mysql \
-p 8080:80 \
-e PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE=100M \
-e PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE=100M \
-e max_execution_time=120 \
-e max_input_time=120 \
-e memory_limit=64M \
-v /root/my-wordpress:/var/www/html/wp-content \
--name my-wordpress \
wordpress:latest
```

There's no problem uploading images to the Wordpress site.

Any idea what may have gone wrong?

Comment: using wordpress:latest may be the problem.  If the version of wordpress in your docker container is "too new", the theme you're trying to upload may not be compatible with it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue using the theme Aurum 2.9.4 + WooCommerce 2.6.4. I'll try to figure out how to solve the problem, then I post the answer here.

Comment: @FernandoPaladini The problem should be caused by things like low limitations set on file upload size and max execution time.

Comment: Yes, I do think so. I gave up on Docker and configured Wordpress on my local Linux machine (without virtual machines). Since I need it only for some tests, there's no problem to me setup everything locally. Anyway, just to the sake of the problem, there's a way to solve this problem in Docker? You've done it? If so, can you please post the answer? This can help me in the future. Sorry for not being able to solve this problem for us.

Comment: Remove the `-d` and show the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup the Official Wordpress with Mariadb docker's container. I sugest using kitematic (alpha) v0.17.1 because it has linking support.

But the important part is to enable volume, to have data persistence, so you can edit **.htaccess** and add at the end of the file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 100M
```

[image: printscreen of this config]